# Display the value from a input box inside popover under the DOM element which creates the dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a newbie and learning by self and started working on projects. Currently  I'm working on drag and drop task for that I'm using jQuery UI to make clone for dragged element. That's all working fine.

But I have a requirement to create a Popover box which contain form inside of it. I want to display the value that entered in the popover dialog box under the corresponding clone element which creating the Popover box. Please check my code below.

```js
var $clone, cloneId;
var wardInfo;
var counter = 1;
$(document).ready(function($) {

  $(".drop-zone").droppable({
    accept: '.drag',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $clone = ui.helper.clone();
      $clone.attr({
        'data-toggle': 'popover',
        'data-placement': 'bottom',
        'data-dismiss': 'close',
        'data-original-title': 'Add Title to Dialog'
      });
      if (!$clone.is('.inside-drop-zone')) {
        $(this).append($clone.addClass('inside-drop-zone').draggable({
          containment: '.drop-zone',
          zIndex: '999'
        }));

        $clone.resizable({
          helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
          handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw, n, s, w, e',
          aspectRadio: true
        });
      }
      cloneId = $clone.attr("id", "clonedElement" + counter);

      wardInfo = '<div class="form-group "><div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-center"><label class="control-label input"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="addValue" placeholder="Enter Value" id="addValue"/></label></div><div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-center"><button id="btntest" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm assignedGroup" type="button" data-target-id="addValue">ADD</button></div></div>';
      console.log(wardInfo);

      $("#clonedElement" + counter).popover({
        html: true,
        content: wardInfo
      });

      $(document).on('click', '#btntest', function() {
        var resDataVal;
        var contentValue = $('#addValue').val();
        alert('Contenet Value: ' + contentValue);

        if (!contentValue == "" || !contentValue == undefined || !contentValue == null) {
          var dataVal = $clone.attr('data-contentValue', contentValue);
          //$("#clonedElement1").popover('hide');
          var resPara = $('<p id="elVal"></p>').insertAfter(this).append(contentvalue);
          $(resPara).append(contentValue);

          $("#clonedElement" + counter).popover('hide');
          resDataVal = $clone.data('contentValue');
          console.log(resDataVal);
        } else {
          alert("Pls enter the data..");
        }
      });
      ++counter;
    }
  });
  $(".drag").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
});
```

```css
.dragLayout {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.drop-zone {
  border: 1px solid #9C9898;
  height: 350px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.drag {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
}
#dialog {
  position: element(#target);
  padding-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
  background: #3a9893;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 10px;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-widget .ui-widget-content {
  padding: 0;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="dragLayout">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="drag"></div>
    <br />
    <div class="drag"></div>
    <br />
    <div class="drag"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <div class="drop-zone"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="addDialog"></div>
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: I have tried this code, but still it could not happen. var resPara = $('<p id="elVal"></p>').insertAfter('#clonedElement'+counter).append(contentvalue);

Comment: I have sorted out this problem, Thanks..